# How to compare pointer to an ascii character?

Tags: c, pointers, command-line

I am trying to write a function that checks to see if all the parentheses are closed (equal amount of open and closed) from a command line argument. 
It is to check for an acceptable input. ./main ( 10 + 10 ) with spaces in between so each parenthesis is its own token in the command line. It is to make sure the command line argument does't look like ./main ( 10 + 10

I have tried changing the '(' to 40 and ')' to 41. I tried to use argv[i] instead of *(argv + i) but I do not have a lot of experience with pointers. (I come from a Java background).

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {

  int i;
  char *outputBase;
  char *helpFlag;
  char **equation;

  equation = NULL;
  /*check for validity of inputs*/
  if (checkAmtArgs(argc) == false || checkParens(argc, argv) == false) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    if (isNumber(argv[i])){
      strcat(*equation, *(argv + i));
    } else if (isOperator(argv[i])) {
      strcat(*equation, *(argv + i));
    } else if (isBase(argv[i])) {
      outputBase = argv[i];
    } else if (isFlag(argv[i])) {
      helpFlag = argv[i];
    } else {
      printf("%s\n", "Exiting program");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}

/*check for valid number of parantheses*/
int checkParens(int argc, char **argv) {
  int i;
  int result;

  int openParen;
  int closeParen;

  openParen = 0;
  closeParen = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
    if (*(argv + i) == '(' ) {
      openParen++;
    } else if (*(argv + i) == ')' ){
      closeParen++;
    }
  }

  if (openParen != closeParen) {
    result = false;
    printError(errorNum, 10);
  } else {
    result = true;
  }

  return result;
}
```

```
main.c: In function ‘checkParens’:
main.c:67:21: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
     if (*(argv + i) == '(' ) {
                     ^~
main.c:69:28: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
     } else if (*(argv + i) == ')' ){
```

Comment: First of all, remember that for any pointer or array `a` and index `i`, the expression `*(a + i)` is *exactly* equal to `a[i]`. Secondly, remember that `argv` is an array of pointers. That means `*(argv + i)` is equal to `argv[i]` which is a pointer to a null-terminated byte string and not a single character.

Comment: `argv` is a list of strings, not a list of characters.

Comment: Your algorithm fails on `)(`.

Comment: also remember that `argv[0]` is not the first argument but the program

Comment: Could I do argv[i][0]?

Comment: @Fragile you cannot just look at the first character of each. For instance under Linux/Unix if you do `/tmp/myprog 123 "(1" aze` then argv[0] is the string `/tmp/myprog`, argv[1] is the string `123`, argv[2] is the string `(1`, argv[3] is the string `aze` and argv[4] is NULL

Comment: As the function shown is *not*  `main()`, please what do you pass in to `checkParens()`, how is it defined and initialised/set?

Comment: "*all the parentheses are closed*". Those parenthesis are expected to appear exactly where?

Comment: As it stands the question could be considered incomplete.

Comment: It is to check for an acceptable input. ./main ( 10 + 10 ) with spaces in between so each parenthesis is its own token in the command line. It is to make sure the command line argument does't look like ./main ( 10 + 10

Comment: Is that supposed to be on a unix system? I'm pretty sure the shell would complain about `(` `)` on the command line.

Comment: @Fragile ok, so put that in your question, in that case yes you can look at only the first character of each arg[i] ... if you are sure the inputs are valid. Note you will have to protect some args for instance using "(" in the call as I did in a previous remark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use **(argv + i) i.e two asterisks since you have created pointer to a pointer.

Comment: @Fragile I tried your code. You need to use two asterisk to deference the values. What error are you getting now?

Comment: That worked. I just need to test it with a command line now perhaps.

Comment: You can try posting a new question for the new command line problem perhaps.

Comment: I did not do the down vote. In fact I do not have 15 rep so I cannot up or downvote haha. Edit (just got 15 rep thanks community!)

Comment: `**(argv + i)` (i.e. `*(*(argv + i) + 0)`) is equivalent to `argv[i][0]`. You're not checking every character of a command line argument, you're checking the first character of all arguments.

Comment: I think that is fine because each parentheses is assumed to be input as its own token (i.e there is a space between the parentheses and the next argument) I specified this for the user the program does't do thorough input checks. So each one would be its own arg right or at the 0 spot?